# Have Multiple lines connecting blobs to center of screen using webcam OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am using *OpenCV BlobDetection* to detect blobs that appear on my webcam. I am trying to use `cv2.arrowedLine` function to draw lines from the center of each *blob* to the middle of the screen.

I have the coordinates of each blob using

```
pts = [k.pt for k in keypoints]
```

When I try and use

```
cv2.arrowedLine(img=frame, pt1=(centre), pt2=(int(pts)), color=(0,0,255), thickness=2)
```

Nothing shows up.

Is there a solution for this?
Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some code first

```
# Standard imports
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
im = cv2.imread("blob.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Set up the detector with default parameters.
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create()

# Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(im)
```

I assume you got this far. Now when you run the following line

```
pts = [k.pt for k in keypoints]
```

pts is a list of coordinate tuples in the form `[(x, y), (x, y), ... ]`. Opencv can't draw an arrow between a single point `center` and a list of points. So we'll have to go over it in a for loop as such

```
pts = [k.pt for k in keypoints]
centre = (200, 320) # This should be changed to the center of your image

for pt in pts:
    pt = tuple(map(int, pt))
    cv2.arrowedLine(img=im, pt1=(centre), pt2=(pt), color=(0, 0, 255), thickness = 2)
```

The line `pt = tuple(map(int, pt))` is used to map all numbers in the list to integers. Just calling int(list) isn't going to work.

If you then look at the result it's as I think you wanted.

```
# Show keypoints
cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[blobs before arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAvPl.jpg)
[blobs with arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTyxZ.jpg)